# fnStandingRedraw shows no records in datatable plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery datatable plugin to display a list of records on my page. I am getting all my data from the server side and handling paganation from the server side as well. I wanted that whenever I referesh the table the page state should be maintained. I use the following plugin to achieve this

```
oTable.fnStandingRedraw();
```

This works fine except if i am on the final page of the table and i delete all records from that page and call the `fnStandingRedraw()` function it shows that the table is empty and when clicking on the previous page it shows all records again.

here is the code for the fnStandingRedraw plugin that i am using

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnStandingRedraw = function (oSettings) {
if (oSettings.oFeatures.bServerSide === false) {
    var before = oSettings._iDisplayStart;

    oSettings.oApi._fnReDraw(oSettings);

    // iDisplayStart has been reset to zero - so lets change it back
    oSettings._iDisplayStart = before;
    oSettings.oApi._fnCalculateEnd(oSettings);
}

// draw the 'current' page
oSettings.oApi._fnDraw(oSettings);
};
```

[Datatable Plugin Link](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: Never heard of that plugin. Would be helpful if you give us a link where you found it so we can understand what it does. Because by looking it the code it seems to me that it just calls oSettings.oApi._fnDraw(oSettings); when bServerSide is true. ???

Comment: I have included the link to the plugin in the question

Comment: I surely know the dataTables plugin:-) I don't know the standingRedraw plugin. But maybe the answer of @Lukasz solved this issue already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct behaviour. This script provide way to draw the table again with keeping filtering/sorting/pagination. So when you be on last page, delete all rows and call standing redraw, datatables stay on that last page and show nothing.

Of course you can try catch this situation by checking the current table lenght:

```
oTable.fnGetData().length
```

and if this piece of code return 0 you can call common redraw function:

```
oTable.fnDraw()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of something like this. but what if i want to throw the user on the second last page? calling `oTable.fnDraw()` will refresh the table and go back to the first page right?